# Descargar Directos de Youtube mediante Youtube-dl en partes de 30 mins

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero descargar directos e ir guardando los videos descargados del directo con una duración de 30 mins, el código para descargar me funciona bien, pero no se como hacer para que a los 30 mins pare y comience otro archivo.

he probado por fuerza bruta, crear una función que se ejecute cada 30 mins y al finalizar la función mate la consola, pero el archivo queda en "mp4.part", y no es lo que quiero

¿Cómo puedo hacer? Graciass

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl


class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)


def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Done downloading, now converting ...')


ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDU-rZs-Ic4'])
```

Comment: Si cortas un video en dos tendrás dos archivos, ninguno de los cuales es un video.

Comment: Te entiendo lo que me dices, pero no me refiero a partir un mp4 en 2, sino a mientras se esta descargando y pasando a mp4  ir creando archivos mp4 de una duración o tamaño determinado.

Comment: Bien díficil lo veo. No es cosa de llegar y copiar los bytes; necesitas armar el MP4 con toda su estructura (pista de video, audio, subtitulos, etc.). El formato es complicado (https://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/mp4-layout.txt)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Te comento, el trabajo "difícil" que me comentas ya lo hace el modulo "Youtube-DL" y el "ffmpeg", si ejecuto mi script unos minutos y cierro la consola el resultado será un "video.mp4.part" si yo renombro a "video.mp4" el video es totalmente valido , con lo cual si se puede hacer lo que comentaba, solo que no encuentro la forma.

Comment: Este link te puede servir: https://itubego.com/youtube1/download-specific-parts-of-youtube-video-2/

Comment: gracias amigo parece un buen programa, pero no me sirve para terminar mi "proyecto"